# Tight upper bounds on trigonometric polynomials

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities, trigonometric-polynomials

According to D. Hajela's chapter in *Open Problems in Communications and Computation* the following question was open as of the late 1980s. I have been unable to find any references so any results or references will be appreciated:

Let $k$ be an arbitrarily large natural number. It is possible to show that there is a sequence of integers $(n_i)_{i\geq 1}$ such that for any $k\geq 1,$ the sequence has an initial segment $n_1,\ldots,n_k \in \mathbb{Z}$ satisfying
$$
\sqrt{\pi k} \leq \max_{\theta \in (0,2\pi]} \left|\sum_{i=1}^k \sin n_i \theta\right|\leq k.
$$
To see this, note that
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \left|\sum_{i=1}^k \sin n_i \theta\right|^2 = \pi k.
$$
Along the same line, it is also known (Rudin-Shapiro polynomials) that there are $n_1,\ldots,n_k \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}$ such that
$$
\max_{\theta \in (0,2\pi]} \left|\sum_{i=1}^k \sin n_i \theta\right|\leq c\sqrt{k}.
$$

**(Open?) Problem from Hajela:**
For all arbitrarily large natural numbers $k$, are there $0<n_1\leq n_2\leq \cdots \leq n_k$ with $n_i$ integers such that
$$
\max_{\theta \in (0,2\pi]} \left|\sum_{i=1}^k \sin n_i \theta\right|\leq c\sqrt{k},
$$
for some constant $c$?

Apparently it is known that
$$
\max_{\theta \in (0,2\pi]} \left|\sum_{i=1}^k \sin n_i \theta\right|\leq ck^{2/3},
$$
but no reference to this is given.

(This open problem is stated to be due to H. Bohr from the 1950's, though no explicit reference is given.)

Comment: Your question asks for a finite sequence of unspecified length $k$ with a certain property.  But I think you really want an infinite sequence such that for all $k$, the first $k$ terms have that property.  (Otherwise, the answer seems trivially positive.)